# Angular 8 scroll to a fragment, doesn't bring the fragment to the top of the page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have a link, by clicking on the link, I want to scroll to a fragment which is at the bottom of the page. When I click on the link, the fragment is working, but it doesn't bring it to the top of the page.

I tried having the using div and section with an id to create the fragment. But, it doesn't bring the div or section to the top of the page.

The code in my app routing module is:

```
 imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    //useHash: true,
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
  })]
```

My component code for link and fragment:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/proposal']" fragment="dcn">{{ dcn }}</a>

<section id="dcn">
Some other html here
</section>
```

Note, I have tried using `useHash:true`, but it doesn't seem to work. I would prefer a solution without `useHash` to be true.

Comment: If the fragment is at the bottom of the page, and there is no white space below it, nothing will bring it to the top of the page. If you can't use your mousewheel or scrollbar to bring it to the top, JavaScript isn't going to be able to.

Comment: Yes, there is content inside the section. In fact there is a table inside the section, and I'm able to scroll to the table. But, the table headers are not displayed as there are being overlapped by the header section. I want to achieve the functionality as in the angular api site: https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule#pipes

Comment: I have asked it as a different question. The link is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978281/angular-8-app-when-using-fragment-is-overlapping-with-header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use code like this to scroll to element:

HTML:

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)"></button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

TS:

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Maybe this helps you.

**Remember:** to page scroll to element, page must have sufficient contents do generate a scroll/scrollbar, otherwise does not have content to scroll.

Comment: The exact same code didn't work but I got an idea from your code :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and here is what I done:

This is the link on my menu component:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/products" fragment="product-one">Product One</a>
```

And this is how it is declared on my Product component...
product.component.html

```
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="product-one"></a>
    <h2 >Product One</h2><br>
  </div>
```

product.component.css

```
.anchor a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -10em;
  }
.anchor {
    position: relative;
  }
```

product.component.ts:

```
  //TODO: Needs to verify if is necessary to declare Router and ActivatedRoute
  constructor( router: Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,) {
   }
```

Have in count that the top attribute of CSS is equivalent of size of menu. On this way, when the scroll happens, it should display the anchored element just below the menu div.

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I have **resolved** this issue by implementing **custom scroll restoration behavior**.

The reason of this behavior is that **page didn't already render** and scrollToPosition no have effect.

There are not a good hack with timeout but it works.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter((e): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll)
    ).subscribe(e => {
      if (e.position) {
        // backward navigation
        setTimeout(() => {viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position); }, 0);
      } else if (e.anchor) {
        // anchor navigation
        setTimeout(() => {viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor); }, 0);
      } else {
        // forward navigation
        setTimeout(() => {viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]); }, 0);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason I could not figure out, the page was scrolling all the way to the bottom, way past the fragment I was targeting. This did the trick to stop that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest following this github answer https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547#issuecomment-503076245

This issue has been ongoing for quite some time.

The above method in my app component as well as the following router configuration worked for me:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    {
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
      enableTracing: false,
      urlUpdateStrategy: 'eager',
      scrollOffset: [0, 85] // this is just for my navbar, might not be applicable to you
    }) ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  
}
```

I hope this helps you. I am using Angular 16 btw. With a much older Angular 8 application, I never had to do any workaround for consistent navigation to an anchor, even with lazyloading images, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have a slightly different scenario but I was also looking for a similar solution with `useHash: true`.

I took the directive approach and below is the code.

#### Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ScrollIntoViewOnClick]'
})
export class ScrollIntoViewOnClickDirective {
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  scrollIntoView() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById(this._elementRef.nativeElement.dataset.sectionId).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });
    }, 200)
  }

  scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<!-- click on here -->
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
   [attr.data-sectionId]="sectionId"
   ScrollIntoViewOnClick>
  Link
</a>

<!-- section to scroll -->
<section #{{sectionId}}
         [id]="sectionId">
  content
</section>
```

Hope this would help :)

Happy coding...