# Angular 8 app, when using fragment is overlapping with header

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a link, by clicking on the link, I want to scroll to a fragment which is at the bottom of the page. When I click on the link, the fragment is working, but the fragment is being overlapped by the header component. Please see the image:

Below is the code from my app.component.html:

```
<div class="layout-wrapper">
  <header>
  <app-header></app-header>
</header>  
  <main id="layout-content" [ngClass]="{ active: menuActive }">
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

On the main tag, I have a css styling to have padding on the top

```
#layout-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 120px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
```

But, when I click on the fragment link it is bringing it to the top and overlapping the header.

My component code for link and fragment:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/proposal']" fragment="dcn">{{ dcn }}</a>

<section id="dcn">
Some other html here
</section>
```

Why isn't the padding is being applied? How to apply the padding?

Actual:
[image: actual]

Expected:
[image: expected]

Comment: is it creating any scroll ?

Comment: Yes, there is content inside the section. In fact there is a table inside the section, and I'm able to scroll to the table. But, the table headers are not displayed as there are being overlapped by the header section. I want to achieve the functionality as in the angular api site: angular.io/api/common/CommonModule#pipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After breaking my head to figure out a solution using css, I looked in the angular routing api and found out the solution, which is using

```
    scrollOffset: [0, 135]
```

in the route options in my app-routing.module.ts file. Now, the fragment starts after 135px, which is the length of my header.

Comment: API for anyone landing in this page: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions