# In angular application target selector href value binding in the url.How to restrict that?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular12

In angular application I am using target selector functionality.But when clicking the menu the href value binding to the URL that points to 404 error page.How to use the target selector within the page without affecting the URL

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-ngipq2?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @user77598 plz check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441089/angular4-scrolling-to-anchor) 0lukasz0 answer

Comment: Try adding `anchorScrolling: 'enabled'` into your `app-routing.module.ts`. I hade a similar case in one project and that seem to do the trick.

Comment: @NarenMurali it's not working

Comment: @Coolis It's nor working