# How to avoid the splash screen from showing every time I click on a navbar link in a SPA?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, splash-screen

I was following [this tutorial](https://plainenglish.io/blog/creating-a-splash-screen-in-angular-for-loading-all-the-data-at-startup-b0b91d9d9f93) and everything worked great, no problems at all... Until I clicked on my navbar links and it showed the splash screen every time I clicked on one of them, refreshes my page and it doesn't even directs you to the section in question. My page is a single page app and the navbar links just re-directs you to different sections of the page.

I'm new in the whole thing so I didn't knew what to do tbh, the only solution I found was using (click)="$event.preventDefault()", but that just makes my navbar links useless.

I followed every step and my code is the exact same from the tutorial, but I'm gonna add it if there's maybe something wrong with it specifically.

The splash screen service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SerLoaderService {
  subject = new Subject();

  subscribe(onNext: any): Subscription {
    return this.subject.subscribe(onNext);
  }

  stop() {
    this.subject.next(false);
  }
}
```

The splash screen component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SerLoaderService } from '../servicios/ser-Loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css'],
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  // The screen starts with the maximum opacity
  public opacityChange = 1;

  public splashTransition: any;

  // First access the splash is visible
  public showSplash = true;

  readonly ANIMATION_DURATION = 1;

  private hideSplashAnimation() {
    // Setting the transition
    this.splashTransition = `opacity ${this.ANIMATION_DURATION}s`;
    this.opacityChange = 0;

    setTimeout(() => {
      // After the transition is ended the showSplash will be hided
      this.showSplash = !this.showSplash;
    }, 1000);
  }

  constructor(private loaderService: SerLoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Somewhere the stop method has been invoked
    this.loaderService.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.hideSplashAnimation();
    });
  }
}
```

The homepage component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SerLoaderService } from '../servicios/ser-Loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
})
export class IndexComponent {
  constructor(private LoadingService: SerLoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.LoadingService.stop();
    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

My navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navegacion" aria-label="fixed navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-around" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 w-100 justify-content-around">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="resaltado" (click)="loginModal(loginmodal)"
                                *ngIf="!EstaLoggeado">Login</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="resaltado" (click)="onLogout()" *ngIf="EstaLoggeado">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#Experiencia" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Experiencia</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#Proyectos">Proyectos</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#Contacto">Contacto</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you very much for the help!

EDIT: I just found out it also doesn't load my routed links. It just shows the splash screen and nothing more lol

Comment: You are using href directly and this will cause the browser to take the request which results in the reloading of the page. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441089/angular4-scrolling-to-anchor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular4 - Scrolling to anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441089/angular4-scrolling-to-anchor)

Comment: Okay this work with my navbar links, the only problem I have is that I have this css= `html { scroll-padding-top: 50px }`, and now it doesn't work, when it scrolls to that section it looks unaligned

Answer (score 0):

When using [angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router), you need to use the [routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) selector, rather than the standard href attribute